# I am trying to use SQL to count the number of rows for each date in my database

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

My database is something like this:

```
Date                        Col2         Col3       Col4
2020-11-02 06:45:16.000     data         data       data
2020-11-02 07:23:23.111     data         data       data
2020-12-14 08:55:44.213     data         data       data
```

I only need the counts of the dates like this:

```
Date          Count
2020-11-02     2
2020-12-14     1
```

I've tried ...

```
select distinct(Date),
       count(*)

from database
```

... but the date format is not my friend. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what database are we talking about?

Comment: I am using a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you can remove the date component by converting to a date and using `group by`:

```
select cast(Date as date), count(*)    
from database
group by cast(Date as date)
order by cast(Date as date);
```

However, various databases also have other methods to do the conversion, such as:

- `date(date)` in MySQL.
- `trunc(date)` in Oracle.
- `date_trunc('day', date)` in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use indeed the count() function which means you'll have to 'group by'. Depending on the RDBMS you're using, you'll also need to format the date to take off the timestamp.

On Mysql you could try:

```sql
select date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d'), count(1)
from your_table
group by date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```